# How to change EmailId of Trailhead account?

Tags: trailhead, user-management

I want to change email id of my trailhead account which is currenly set to my organization Email to my personal Email.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same question once. I wrote to suppprt and got the following answer:

> It is not possible to change the email address of the trailhead
>   account. In this case, we suggest you create a new trailhead account
>   with the required email address. By using merge process we can merge
>   badges to the new account.

Please find the suggested solution below:

1. Create a new trailhead account with your personal E-mail address.
2. Merge the old account with the above newly created account. Here is how to do that [Trailhead Self-Service Account Merge](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/help?article=Trailhead-Self-Service-Account-Merge)

Comment: Were you able to merge trailhead accounts?

Comment: Yes, I merged my accounts successfully. If you face any issue with that, you better contact support to help you.

Comment: The problem I have is once you merge, it's still creating playgrounds with old email, which may not even exist.

Comment: I can't create a new account because the email is already associated with the existing account